# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta SQL que permita determinar si varios campos en un registro estén vacíos (no nulos)?

Tags: sql

Necesito generar una consulta SQL que me permita detectar si en un registro hay por lo menos un campo que este vacío; la idea es que estoy trabajando en Laravel, utilizo modales de bootstrap y en mi lógica no requiero que el cliente haga demasiada interacción con los datos de la base de datos, así que pensaba hacer que el propio motor de SQL me haga este proceso (aunque la opción de manejarlo mediante Laravel es la más evidente pero sería bueno que esto lo haga solo el motor de SQL).

La idea es que mi sistema haga un pre-registro a dos tablas y que un segundo usuario tenga que completar ese registro, lo cual se le avisa a este segundo usuario que debe de completar el registro ingresando a la plataforma; para esto hay 2 fases de validación:

1. La primera es validar la existencia de ambos registros en ambas tablas respectivamente.

Si no existe, se crea los pre-registros (estos solo se crean con el ID correspondiente, con los demás campos vacíos) y si existe, pasaría a:

2. La segunda es verificar si los datos de cada registro están completos.

Si están completos, pasan directo a la etapa final pero si no están completos avisa al segundo usuario que sus datos no están completos y debe de llenarlos posteriormente.

La etapa final (siempre se ejecuta) es realizar un "check in" en una tabla de registro.

Así que me preguntaba si SQL puede verificar sin la necesidad de validar si esta vacío cada campo en un WHERE separado por un OR, o si de plano debo de hacer una consulta con la función where() (find no me sirve ya que no utilizo el campo id sino uno personalizado) de Laravel y traer el registro y validar cada campo resultante para indicarle al cliente lo que debe hacer o no.

¿Cuál sería la opción más viable? O si esto se puede hacer directamente en Laravel, sería mucho más fácil.

PD: Había visto un intento de consulta donde un chico pregunta lo mismo pero enfocado a los valores nulos, esta consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE ANY(t.* IS NULL)
```

En mi caso sería identificar si hay vacíos en los campos

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE ANY(t.* = '')
```

Claro exceptuando el ID correspondiente, aunque no espero que me retorne un registro, espero que me retorne un dato booleano y así determinar que faltan datos por los que llenar... una pequeña aclaración, el segundo usuario no tiene la obligación de completar esos registros, pero el primer usuario le avisa al segundo que puede llenar los datos cuando quiera pero que siempre se le tomará como un usuario visitante sin datos (tengo 4 tipos del segundo usuario y el visitante es uno de ellos)

PD2: Esta validación que quiero hacer solamente quiero que la haga el servidor y no el cliente.

PD3: Con esta consulta, se puede adaptar para que verifique todas columnas de un registro exceptuando el ID donde dice "@YourValue"?

```
SET @YourValue=ISNULL(NULLIF(@YourValue,' '), NULL)
```

Me gustaría una consulta compacta, sencilla, que no me tome muchas líneas de código, si SQL o Laravel puede hacer esto, genial sino pues me toca a la vieja usanza pero en verdad espero que si haya una solución a lo que requiero.

**Actualización**

La idea es la siguiente, inserto en dos tablas solo un ID (en el caso de una tabla p.ej. la tabla persona su cédula), la tabla persona tiene sus atributos cédula como clave principal, nombres, apellidos, dirección, teléfono, correo (p.ej.) y el pre-registro queda así:

```
INSERT INTO persona(cedula, nombres, apellidos, direccion, telefono, correo) VALUES(999999999, '', '', '', '', '');
```

Como se nota en la inserción, dejo los demás datos en vacíos (blank) y este es un pre-registro que hace el usuario que realiza check-in de entrada, a lo que me interesa es en una consulta sea un procedimiento almacenado u otro método de SQL identificar, verificar, detectar si todos o por lo menos uno de los campos exceptuando el ID están vacíos para indicarle al segundo usuario que aún debe de completar el registro (un UPDATE), qué esta consulta me devuelva un booleano identificando que true es que aún le falta llenar sus datos o false si no es necesario porque ya los lleno. Por cierto, este aviso se le imprime en un ticket o recibo que se le entrega al segundo usuario. Espero hacerme entender con esto, no creo que haya la necesidad de dar esquema de mi base de datos para identificar si hay campos que no están completos.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con " detectar si en un registro hay por lo menos un campo que este vacío"? ¿Tienes un mapa de tu base de datos para ilustrar tu pregunta y sea más fácil orientarte?

Comment: @FernandoTorres Ahí actualice la descripción de mi problema, espero que así comprenda lo que quiero decir, y no importa el esquema de mi base de datos, solo necesito verificar de un registro (row) si hay datos en blanco (blank) y claro, exceptuando la clave principal ya que esta es la única que se guarda al momento de hacer esa pre-inserción.

Comment: De ser posible lo es, pero has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: @BetaM Por el momento no he intentado nada con respecto en SQL pero lo que hacía antes era obtener el registro y validar cada campo si estaba vacío y ahí notificar al sistema que aún no se ha registrado los datos que faltan en el pre-registro, pero quiero que el motor de base de datos haga eso por mi y en vez del servidor con Laravel pues no sé si estoy obrando bien o solo me estoy complicando la vida, qué opina usted?

Comment: ¿Con qué motor de base de datos trabajas? Si no quieres escribir la consulta, seguro se encuentra la forma de _generarla_, solo que esto puede resultar en una cantidad significativamente mayor de código que la propia consulta original, por no hablar de la complejidad.

Comment: Trabajo con Microsoft SQL Server, aunque siento que nadie me podrá colaborar con esto y veo que esto no se puede hacer en SQL directo sino traer el registro completo y validarlo por cada campo directo en el controlador especifico en mi proyecto de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Si después de concatenar todos los campos sigue resultando en cadena vacía, es uno de los registros que buscas:

```
SELECT *
  FROM persona
  WHERE concat( cedula, nombres, apellidos, direccion, telefono, correo ) = ''
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer un select y comprobar que los campos no estén vacíos uno por uno:

```
select count(t.*) 
from table t 
where t.campo1='' 
   or t.campo2=''... etc
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica tu consulta. Un buen ejemplo es la otra respuesta en esta pregunta :) Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin ninguna descripción se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edit la respuesta para añadir una descripción con lo que hace el código compartido y cómo resuelve el problema de la pregunta. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.